# java file reader weird output

Tags: java, filereader

I set up a FileReader, and opened a file to read, but it gives me a weird output, that I can't seem to fix:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class FileReading {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

    FileReader file = new FileReader("/Users/danielpersonius/Desktop/test.rtf");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    String text = "";
    String line = reader.readLine();

    while (line != null){
        // So here, we want to print until it reaches 'null'
        text += line;
        line = reader.readLine();
    }

    System.out.println(text);
}
}
```

This is my output:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1265\cocoasubrtf200{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0
>   Helvetica;}{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\f0\fs24
>   \cf0 TEST}

TEST is what the rtf file says, but how do I get rid of all the other stuff I obviously don't want?
I'm on an IMac with OS X Mavericks

Comment: >.< An RTF file obviously contains stuff other than the text. Otherwise it couldn't contain styles. Use TXT for plain text.

Comment: Use a reader that reads rtf.

Comment: Alright, I fixed it, thanks for the help. On my mac i use TextEdit, so i just clicked 'Convert to Plain Text' like you said. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your are probably creating your file in TextEdit.  TextEdit does not save files as a raw text file.  Instead it saves it in a RTF (Rich Text File) format which embeds formating commands.   You need to use a text editor that can create an ASCII text file.

[For more information on RTF.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same editor you use to write your code to create your "test.*" file :)

Answer (score 1):

On your test file go to format in the toolbar, then click convert to .txt file for conversion.

This change would get rid of the weird output